# How to display the data in 10 columns and 8 rows?

Tags: file-io, fortran, output

Think I have a dataset (numbers) in txt file. It has 10 columns and 80 raws.

I opened, read this data and stored in a array in a fortran program.
Then I write this data in array again to the another txt file. Then the data displayed as continuously.
I need to display it as 10 columns and 8 rows again in this new txt file.
How can I do this?

Ex:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer::n
    real,dimension(10,8)::data
    
    open(unit=7,file='C:\USERS\SAM\DOCUMENTS\FORTRAN\DATA.TXT')
    
    read (7,*) data

    open(unit=8,file='C:\USERS\SAM\DOCUMENTS\FORTRAN\TESTDATA.TXT')
    
    do n=1,80
         write (8,*) data
    end do

end program test
```

Comment: Remove the ```do``` and ```end do``` lines and just use formatted output; e.g. ```write( 8,"( 10(1x,e11.4))" ) data```. BTW, I would avoid using a keyword like ```data``` as the name of a variable.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It is important to write a good title for your question. Do not use unspecific titles like "Regarding a Fortran program" or similar, use titles that tell what you want to do.

Comment: What is going wrong in that code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `do` loop, you're writing out the whole array. So you'll end up having your output be 80 times longer than you'd like. Index the array so that it only prints out one row at a time, as in

```
do n=1,10
    write(8,'(8(1x,e10.4))') data(n,:)
end do
```

Indexing using `(n,:)` is effectively saying "the n-th row, all columns".

That should work if the array has been read in properly, which I'm not comfortable enough with Fortran to say whether your `read` statement will work as intended. If someone else could comment on that, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The loop now overflows the first index of the array when going to 80. The read will or will not work depending on the input file formay.

Answer (score 0):

No loop is strictly needed on output: every time the format repeats it will start a new record (i.e. start a new line).

There's a few too many "magic numbers" here for my taste, and, whilst "rows"/"columns" may, indeed, reflect the storage order in Fortran, they don't sit comfortably with how you usually describe matrices in maths.

But anyway.

```
program test
   implicit none
   real, dimension(10,8) :: MyData
    
   open( 7, file='C:\USERS\SAM\DOCUMENTS\FORTRAN\DATA.TXT' )
   read( 7, * ) MyData
   close( 7 )

   open( 8, file='C:\USERS\SAM\DOCUMENTS\FORTRAN\TESTDATA.TXT' )
   write( 8, "( 10( 1x, e11.4 ) )" ) MyData       ! no loop needed
   close( 8 )

end program test
```

Comment: Actually, I only remembered which index is which in linear algebra by remembering that Fortran (which I know well but learned later) is supposed to be "column major".

Comment: Coding both in Fortran and C++ I confuse myself regularly with this!